# SQL Where IN Order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in SQL

```
video : ID, TITLE
join_video_clicked : ID_VIDEO, NB_VIEW
```

My actual SQL Query :

```
SELECT ID,TITLE FROM video WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID_VIDEO FROM join_video_clicked ORDER BY CLICKED DESC LIMIT 0,24) AS TEMP)
```

Explain 1 :

```
SELECT ID_VIDEO FROM join_video_clicked ORDER BY CLICKED DESC LIMIT 0,24
```

This query get 24 ids the most viewed

Explain 2 :

```
SELECT ID,TITLE FROM video WHERE ID IN (!!!SUBQUERY!!!)
```

This query find id and title with subquery

Explain my problem :

The result of my actual Query is randomized, i have the 24 most viewed but not in good order.
I have search on google, my friend, i find ORDER BY FIELD, i would like your help for adjust my query with ORDER BY FIELD or other way.

I Little more difficult :

I would like get the 24 most viewed from a custom category : 
my query :

```
SELECT ID,TITLE,THUMB FROM video WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ID_VIDEO FROM join_video_clicked WHERE ID_VIDEO IN (SELECT ID_VIDEO FROM join_video_category WHERE ID_CATEGORY = 8) ORDER BY CLICKED DESC) AS TEMP) LIMIT 0,24
```

Comment: Your syntax suggests MySQL, so I'm removing the "sql-server" tag.

Comment: What is in `NB_View` column? Is it a  number of views?

Comment: Yes number of view : INT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit `join` instead.  If the table `join_video_clicked` has no duplicates, then just do:

```
SELECT v.ID, v.TITLE
FROM video v JOIN
     join_video_clicked vc
     ON v.id = vc.id_video
ORDER BY vc.clicked DESC
LIMIT 24
```

Otherwise, you'll need an aggregation:

```
SELECT v.ID, v.TITLE
FROM video v JOIN
     join_video_clicked vc
     ON v.id = vc.id_video
GROUP BY v.ID, v.TITLE
ORDER BY MAX(vc.clicked) DESC
LIMIT 24
```

Comment: i have updated my post, there are other query and it's work as i want !